# Combining \obeyspaces and \read

Tags: plain-tex

It seems to be impossible to combine `\obeyspaces` and `\read` in the following manner:

```
\newread\myread
\openin\myread=myfile.txt
  \obeyspaces  % Deleting this line removes the error
  \read\myread to \myinput
  \myinput
\closein\myread
```

The `\tracingall` doesn't really help me for understanding the problem.

Comment: Your example has no `\obeyspaces`: please edit your example so we can see what you are doing (probably including an example `myfile.txt`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to preserve normal spaces around the `\read` syntax:

```
\newread\myread
  \def\doread#1#2{\immediate\read#1 to #2}
\immediate\openin\myread=myfile.txt
  {\obeyspaces
   \doread\myread\myinput\immediate\write20{\myinput}%
   \doread\myread\myinput\immediate\write20{\myinput}%
   \doread\myread\myinput\immediate\write20{\myinput}%
   \doread\myread\myinput\immediate\write20{\myinput}%
}
\immediate\closein\myread

\bye
```

---

```
00
1 1
2  2
3   3
```

---

produces

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012)
(./rd55.tex
00 
1 1 
2  2 
3   3 
 )
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which answers my question. How could I have found out that I need to preserve "normal" (what is the differences to the `\obeyspaces`?) spaces around the `\read` syntax to solve problems like this on my own in the future?

Comment: obeyspaces makes space into an active character with a definition similar to `~` so that it always typesets as a real space and is never dropped by the input scanner. spaces around tex primitives need to delimit the arguments but be dropped... not sure where best to learn these things other than asking here (after 25 years of using tex it's not always easy to remember how you pick these things up at the start:-)

Comment: from the TeXbook perhaps? ;-)

Comment: @jfbu not really. TeXBook, or actually more simply just looking at the plain or latex sources will tell you the definition of \obeyspaces, but it takes some experience to spot the implications of that definition on other macros.